# OneLogin Java-SAML cannot read SAML response

Tags: java, saml, onelogin

I have implemented SAML support for my application. I used **Java-SAML** from **OneLogin**. In my local tests everything works fine. I used a Ping Federate IdP server to do my tests, where my app acts as an SP. When testing the solution with the customer's IdP, I get the following error:

> SAML Response not found, Only supported HTTP_POST Binding

I don't have access to the customer's IdP configuration, but I doublechecked that he has set up the assertion response to be HTTP_POST and I also confirmed that by using a SAML Tracer extension in FireFox. I do get a SAML POST response from the IdP, but I still get this error.

This is a screenshot from the SAML Tracer. I really don't know what to do next. Do you have any ideas?

[image]

I logged the request parameters in my code before doing anything and indeed, there is no SAMLResponse parameter. How can this be explained? The SAML Tracer shows that there is a SAMLResponse, but I don't get one. I am using Tapestry 3 in my app. Does this affect anything?

Answer (score 1):

To get samlresponse you need to define acs url with argument as Samlresponse then in that argument it will be fetched.

Try ping federate IDP, it works best using self signed certificates too.

Also there is a third party DLL provider for SAML with ping federate

https://krinteltech.com/?page_id=1340

You can try that too